# An error in the StructureBuilder (Biopython) based on Anaconda2 for pySCA tutorial, why the protein chain is discontinuous?

Tags: python, biopython, pdb

I ran the S1A serine protease calculations follow the tutorial of pySCA 
(Statistical Coupling Analysis in python [Link](http://reynoldsk.github.io/pySCA/tutorials.html)).

However, something wrong on the StructureBuilder (Biopython based on Anaconda2).

"WARNING: Chain %s is discontinuous..."

How can be fixed?

I will really appreciate if some of you can point it out.

THE ERROR OUTPUT:

```
Mingling@Mingling-PC MINGW32 ~/Desktop/pySCA
$ ./runAllNBCalcs_2.sh
C:\Users\Mingling\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain E is discontinuous at line 2569.
PDBConstructionWarning)
C:\Users\Mingling\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain I is discontinuous at line 2570.
PDBConstructionWarning)
C:\Users\Mingling\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain E is discontinuous at line 2580.
PDBConstructionWarning)
C:\Users\Mingling\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain I is discontinuous at line 2758.
PDBConstructionWarning)
Error!!! Something wrong with PDB id or path.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and include the relevant code in your question. If you provide a standalone example, chances are much higher that somebody will figure out the answer.

Comment: It is a `Warning` not an `error`. Most `pdb` files contain errors or discontinuities so it's pretty common to have this kind of warnings in `biopython`.